# Update table row from the values in Modal pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click of Edit button, Jquery Modal pop up is displayed with corresponding row values inside it.
When I click on submit button inside the modal popup, I want the edited values from pop up to be displayed back in that table row without reloading the page.

Below is my table structure.

```
<table class="expenseTable">
    <tr>
               <th>Date</th> 
               <th>Expense Info</th> 
               <th>Category</th> 
               <th>Amount</th> 
               <th>Edit</th>
               <th>Delete</th>
             </tr>
         <tr id="1soxc">
         <td>26-Mar-2018</td>   
         <td>Cloth</td> 
         <td>Shopping</td>  
         <td>100</td>   
         <td>Edit</td>
         <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I tried the below code. But it's not working

```
form = dialog.find('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    updateExpense();
});



   function updateExpense() {
        let updatedExpense = {
//Values from the modal pop up
            date: $('.udate').val(),
            expenseInfo: $('.uinfo').val(),
            category: $('#ucategory option:selected').text(),
            amount: $('.uamount').val()
        };
        console.log('updating', updatedExpense);
       $(this).parent().find('td:eq(0)').append(updatedExpense.date);
```

Comment: jQuery event handlers (like your `submit` handler) will scope `this` as the element that invoked the event, however `updateExpense` is just a regular function. In that context, `this` is not going to retrieve any sort of element. I'd imagine you want something like `$("#1soxc > td:eq(0)").text(updatedExpense.date);` instead.

Comment: Tried it, but no luck

Comment: Are you trying to change the row that's already there, or add another row with the values? As you can [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/zukdg3L6/1/), the code in my comment above should update the existing row just fine.

Comment: I am trying to update the existing row.

Comment: const expenseId = localStorage.getItem('expenseId');
 $("#${expenseId} > td:eq(0)").data(updatedExpense.date);

Comment: That is not how you concatenate in JavaScript. The code in your previous comment will look for an element with the ID "(expenseId)" instead of the variable value. You must do `$("#" + expenseId + " > td:eq(0)")`.

Comment: At second glance it looks like you were trying to use a template literal, which is perfectly valid for concatenation in JS. *However*, template literals are encapsulated with backticks (`\``) as opposed to double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Initially, I tried using a string literal, but that didn't work either, hence tried all possibilities. For some reason, it's not working